# This tag is crap

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags

What a load of [crap](/questions/tagged/crap):

> The C.R.A.P. (Change Risk Analysis and Predictions) index is designed to analyze and predict the amount of effort, pain, and time required to maintain an existing body of code.

This [crap](/questions/tagged/crap) describes questions that would probably not be a good fit for Stack Overflow. Seriously, why does [crap](/questions/tagged/crap) like this exist at all?

Even if [crap](/questions/tagged/crap) was a real topic, which apparently [it is](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=210434), questions about whatever [crap](/questions/tagged/crap) the description refers to — code maintenance and other software metrics — would seem more suited to Programmers than Stack Overflow. But of course, considering that the word [crap](/questions/tagged/crap) itself refers to something that's completely unrelated to programming, and something that would very possibly piss people off, and that it's really not a meaningful tag anyway, I think questions on either site can do without this [crap](/questions/tagged/crap).

Comment: Something tells me this post is going to go through quite a lot of editing....

Comment: Although I agree that most CRAP questions would be more suitable for Programmers than Stack Overflow, I don't see what's wrong with the tag. The index might be obscure, but it's real.

Comment: @Bart, I thought Unicorns were supposed to be rude because they were the weaponized forms of ponies, or something. Vocabulary's not nice in war.

Comment: @Yannis You might want to rephrase that, or I'll get ready to migrate...

Comment: @Yannis, maybe something a little less risky, like `[c-r-a-p]`... No, on second thought it looks even worse.

Comment: I agree; this tag is C.R.A.P. However, as it's only got 6 questions and as you're a mod do you really need meta approval to kerblam it?

Comment: @Bart There's (currently) only one question, and it can't be migrated, it's older than 60 days. (you've been around long enough to know I won't take any chances when it comes to migrating to ProgSE ;)

Comment: Two of said questions aren't even about C.R.A.P. So I removed the tag from them.

Comment: @ben: At least I'm nice enough to *ask* unlike some people...

Comment: Could it not be synonymized with the [metrics] tag?

Comment: I get the point @Bolt, and yes it is nicer, but it's not like you're asking to burninate [tag:database] (in my dreams) or even [tag:snow].

Comment: @Bart I really don't think creating a synonym silently changing "crap" to _anything else_ is a good idea. Also it's pretty funny that the only editing so far is on the blam reference.

Comment: @badp C.R.A.P. seems to explicitly refer to software metrics and is not really significant enough (or so it seems) to warrant its own tag. I don't see why they can't been synonymized given that the only legitimate reason to use [crap] as a tag would be to refer to C.R.A.P.

Comment: @Bart: Post that as an answer maybe? (I'll remove the wiki on mine - no point in using that crap here when we have enough [tag:crap] to deal with already.)

Comment: That tag is definitely a bad smell.  Seems like it would be on-topic for the [Project Management](http://pm.stackexchange.com/) site though.

Comment: I think the real question is: If the tag is legit, what will you do when Lance Roberts changes everything to `c**p`?

Comment: @Lorem Ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Eu sed probo facer, eam vero tincidunt sadipscing id. Oportere senserit ei ius, alterum vituperata reformidans cu has, sit ut prima consul. Wisi iudicabit vel an. Vix modus moderatius ut, vix quis option argumentum te. Te sit viris putent. Usu ne diam praesent, electram voluptatum ea mea. Numquam fabulas scaevola no pro, vix integre voluptatibus ei. Officiis pericula qui ea. Nec et nostrud partiendo, an sed iuvaret lucilius accommodare. Pri audiam tibique ei, rebum cotidieque nam ut. Ex quando graeco mea, nec cetero theophrastus etiam.

Comment: @Bart It's not exactly _hard_ to imagine "crap" being used to mean "poo" by newer users who are confused about the tagging system. Already today the tag was "mysteriously" applied to two other questions that had nothing to do with CRAP, as J. Steen reports.

Comment: @badp Whether it erroneously remains [crap] or gets retagged to [metrics], a cleanup would be needed in either case. I don't really see tag abuse as a reason not to make the synonym. We could of course implement a popup asking if they meant c.r.a.p. or poo, but that would be one step too far imho. ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Blam](http://www.newgrounds.com/portal/view/558516) this piece of [crap](/questions/tagged/crap)!

Answer (score 8):

Looking at [what C.R.A.P refers to](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=210575), it seems to relate to software metrics. And guess what.. we have a [metrics](/questions/tagged/metrics) tag already on Stack Overflow.

Given that C.R.A.P. does not seem to be significant enough to warrant its own tag, why not synonymize the two? Users who legitimately want to tag their question related to C.R.A.P. (even if that might not be a great fit for SO) would end up with a relevant tag.

Added bonus is of course that others can no longer add the tag for less serious purposes.

Comment: Just noticed we have [tag:code-metrics] too, wouldn't you know it.

Comment: Gah, and here I was actually surprises we didn't already have software-metrics.

Comment: If you're going after metrics there's also [tag:website-metrics] and [tag:quality-metrics] (which has a CRAP question)...

Comment: Yeah, I can't agree with a synonym, with only four questions and chances are, people wanting to use it for something other than the metric, better to just edit the four questions and let the tag drift away (lest people misappropriate it).

Comment: @casperOne Fair enough, retag it to metrics (or something else appropriate) and let it be gone.

Answer (score 3):

Keep it, but rename it to [crap-index](/questions/tagged/crap-index) or something similar. It's still [crap](/questions/tagged/crap) anyway — it's right in the **name**, for [crap](/questions/tagged/crap)'s sake!

Comment: mental note: Rename that super seekrit project I'm working on to something terribly offensive, and flood SO with questions about it when it's finally released (6-8 weeks).

Comment: I suggest renaming it to something more polite instead. FECES: "Forecasted Explosions Caused by Evolution in Software."